# show a specific symbol after the last letter in an input field

Tags: javascript, input, cursor

how can I show this symbol "|" after the last letter in an input field?
Example: if the user enter any text in the input, lets assume he entered "abc" i want it to look like this in the input field "abc|" -to add (|) after the last character using javascript..

the idea is, I have a disabled input so there is no typing cursor appears  in it, i want this symbol "|" to be like the typing cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something like the following. You can use javascript's setInterval function to run at each chosen interval - in this case `500ms`.

Each time check if the `placeholder === '|'` and if so toggle it.

See running code example below.

```js
var inpt = document.getElementById("input-box"),
 ltr = document.getElementById("ltr");

ltr.onclick = function () {
inpt.value += "Q"
}

setInterval(function() {
   if (document.getElementById('input-box').placeholder === '|') {
       document.getElementById('input-box').placeholder = '';
   } else {
       document.getElementById('input-box').placeholder = '|';
   }

    if(document.getElementById('input-box').value.slice(-1) === 'Q'){
       document.getElementById('input-box').value += '|';
    } else if(document.getElementById('input-box').value.slice(-1) === '|') {
        document.getElementById('input-box').value = document.getElementById('input-box').value.slice(0, -1);
    }
}, 500);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-box" disabled>
   <button id="ltr">Letter Q
</button>
```

Comment: i want the "|" to be after the last character, so when the user click on the button the "|" position become after the last character https://jsfiddle.net/crhLd9mm/1/